# A server or scripting issue

Tags: apache, tomcat, cas

I am recieving an error in https

```
   HTTP Status 404 - /cas/login

    type Status report

     message /cas/login

    description The requested resource (/cas/login) is not available.
     Apache Tomcat/7.0.23
```

when i open the same link in http it gives an output (an unknown language)

```
    <html>
     <head></head>
     <body>
    <pre>???�?? </pre>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Why is it so...? Is this an server issue or script issue? I feel it as a Server issue?? If so please share a remedy for it...

Comment: Application on Tomcat is not deployed correctly, or it's configuration is incorrect.

Comment: configuration is incorrect?? actually it was working properly for last two days... but suddenly such an eror is making me tensed...

Answer (score 0):

"The requested resource (/cas/login) is not available." generally indicates that cas was not correctly deployed or Tomcat couldn't load it properly. Could you plz examine the contents of either the catalina  or the cas.log files and report back?